# is whoisthisdomain by nirsoft safe?

Tags: windows, domain, whois, domain-security

I have been in the domain world for about 3 months now but have already been a victim of front running. I use the command line now, but I don't like typing commands and sometimes I get "server failed" errors.

I just found out about `whoisthisdomain` by nirsoft, a mature piece of software that has already had various previous versions:http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/whois_this_domain.html

But is it really safe or not? I don't have that much technical knowledge but it shows an option when opened where you can  choose whether to:

`use xx.whois-servers.net to get the correct whois server instead of internal server lists`

Does this mean our search queries are handled by their own servers by default and more importantly can they store the queries?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using public whois servers, is that sometimes they can save the results and then steal them from you. To that effect, online whois webpages are typically not "safe".

It looks like this app by Nirsoft polls the whois servers directly and gives you the results locally.

So if your definition of `safe` is "nobody can steal my results", then yes this may be *safe*